# Migrate an FTP site Based on IIS version 6.1 to an IIS version 10

Tags: iis, ftp

as per the title i am searching for a good method to migrate a Ftp site based on IIS from an old windows server 2008 to a new windows server 2022.
From IIS 6.1 to IIS 10
I thought that the best procedure to follow was:

1. Extract configuration from windows server 2008 via IIS Shared Configuration, Export configuration.
2. Import that configuration inside windows server 2022 IIS via Shared Configuration
3. move all data from windows server 2008 to windows server 2022.

It seems it is not working, in fact on step 2 the iis manager on windows server 2022 becomes Not responding and I can't proceed this way. That Import can be done only if the IIS version is the same.

Then I tried with msdeploy:

1. msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="Default FTP Site" -dest:archivedir=D:\Archivedir\
2. copy archivedir to the other server
3. C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy -verb:sync -source:archivedir=D:\Archivedir -dest:apphostconfig="Default FTP Site"

the msdeploy apporach rebuilt the data structure and the ftp configuration.

Comment: Why is it important that it is on 2008? Is an ftp site not an ftp site?  What "configuration"?

Comment: I am not an expert of iis and ftp server based on iis. I thought that all the configurations of the ftp were inside the IIS Manager. Is not that way?

Comment: Experienced server administrators can simply open up `applicationHost.config` and copy FTP related fragments over to the new server. Sadly I don't know any good automatic tools for FTP migration. Don't use Shared Configuration, as that feature typically assumes all servers involved are using the same Windows release.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above seems to work only with websites and not ftpsites

Answer (score 2):

The error I got was that I had not installed the ftp server in the destination server.

First go to the destination server, open server manager install IIS and FTP.

Second install Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6 on the destination server and on the original server.
on the original server do:

1)c:\program files\iis\microsoft web deploy 3\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="Default FTP Site" -dest:archivedir=D:\Archivedir\

2)copy archivedir to the other server

3)on the destination server do
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy -verb:sync -source:archivedir=D:\Archivedir -dest:apphostconfig="Default FTP Site"

after be sure to check folder permissions because they might not be transfered

it is working this way.
also read first
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above

https://www.coveros.com/msdeploy-brief-overview-for-sync/